# Material UI styles fully broken when injected as content script

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a little browser/chrome extension using material UI that is injecting a content script to LinkedIn and XING. The XING page looks actually like this (everything working fine):
[image: Material UI input fields working fine]

But when the page gets loaded at LinkedIn, the input card looks broken:
[image: broken input at LinkedIn]

I was already trying to find out if any global CSS class is overwriting something, but I couldn't find it out.
Does anybody have an idea, what could cause this behaviour? 
I'm injecting the React App like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router
  } from "react-router-dom";
  import Overlay from './overlay'

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
window.addEventListener("loadend", init, false);


function init() {

    var div = document.createElement( 'div' )
    document.body.appendChild( div )
    div.id = 'voyager-extension-overlay'
    div.style.position = 'fixed'
    div.style.zIndex = '10'

    ReactDOM.render( <Router><Overlay /></Router> , div)

}
```

Any good hint is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the default styling of material being lost.  Likely this has to do with the order of css imports.  I would have a close look at the order in both cases in the elements tab of dev tools.

Comment: Do you have an idea, how to prevent it? Seems like the standard LinkedIn CSS is somehow overwriting Material UI styling .. I can't change the order of the imports, as I'm just injecting my Javascript after the page load of the LinkedIn page.

Comment: So I've seen now, that LinkedIn has a global "font-size" value: ```html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}``` that is overwriting and breaking also the material-ui values. Any idea how to prevent this overwrite?